# Renewenvironment multicols

Tags: environments, multicol, renewcommand

I have a larger document in which the text is often set in columns with multicols.
Now I have to remove the columns for the print layout and would like to redefine the multicols environment.

Unfortunately, "Renewenvironment" doesn't work that easily, apparently because the number of columns is specified in the environment.

Does anyone have any good advice for me?

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\blindtext

\begin{multicols}{2} 
\blindtext

\end{multicols} 

\blindtext
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Is removing `\begin{multicols}{2}` and `\end{multicols}` an option?

Comment: Not really, there are hundreds of occurrences and I need to restore the file with columns after printing.
So for future prints it would be better to find a solution that changes the behaviour of multicols.

Comment: you can redefine it to have the same argument structure and do nothing? what did you try, what error did you get?

Comment: I tried  \renewenvironment but cannot handle the "{2}" in \begin{multicols}{2}. The 2 was written in the text after the change of the environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `multicols` environment has a mandatory argument, which you want to just ignore, and an optional argument for text to be printed before switching to multicolumn format, typically a section title.

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\RenewDocumentEnvironment{multicols}{mO{}}{\par#2\par}{\par}

\begin{document}

\blindtext

\begin{multicols}{2}
\blindtext
\end{multicols}

\begin{multicols}{2}[\section{Title}]
\blindtext
\end{multicols}

\blindtext

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. It works very well and is really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The following should work

```
\DeclareDocumentEnvironment{multicols}{mO{}+b}{%
    \IfValueT{#2}{\notblank{#2}{#2}{}}#3}{}
```

It requires to load `etoolbox` (for `\notblank`) and perhaps `xparse` (for `\Declare...`) if your LaTeX version is too old.